# Exists a network switch with integrated KVM over IP in 1U?

Tags: networking, switch, keyboard-video-mouse

I am looking into a new hosting infrastructure that have two servers and a switch.
Since I have only 1U available for the switch, I was looking for a appliance that have KVM over IP integrated, so I could do reboots and preboot maintenance.

Do you know one?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know of such a device. However, have you considered purchasing servers that have remote management cards  (LOM, iLOM, DRAC, etc.)? Those will give you much more functionality than a KVMoIP device will. A simple KVM switch will *only* provide KVM functionality. A remote management card, however, will perform KVM functions as well as providing power control, ipmi, remote/virtual media, etc.

Comment: Umm, no, I didn't know about them, but I guess that a server with this card are very expensive

Comment: Not necessarily - I have purchased Dell servers with DRAC cards for at little as $2000 US. In my experience, KVMoIP devices are quite expensive as well.

Comment: +1, These sort of cards are definitely the way to go. Many servers already have this functionality built in, so you don't need to buy an extra add-in card. The card to add to servers are generally cheap considering the functionality you get.

Comment: I would like to recommend supermicro servers, which have on-boad IPMI 2.0 with KVM-over-IP support even if the price is starting below 1000$

Answer (score 4):

HP sell [THESE](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13474_div/13474_div.html), I'm pretty sure they'll do what you need.

Comment: Oh now that's slick.

Comment: They also cost $2-6,000 depending on features. Though they are exactly what he's asking for.

Comment: Dude you need to work your sales team harder, you can get ~75% discount on these - although I have to admit I don't buy them as I'm a blade-only kind of guy.